# Python returns changes the return dimensions if called with extra return

Tags: python, function, return

I have this function that perform pooling on an image
'''

```
def pool_forward(A_prev, hparameters, mode = "max"):


(m, n_H_prev, n_W_prev, n_C_prev) = A_prev.shape

f = hparameters["f"]
s = hparameters["stride"]

n_H = int(1 + (n_H_prev - f) / s)
n_W = int(1 + (n_W_prev - f) / s)
n_C = n_C_prev

A = np.zeros((m, n_H, n_W, n_C))              

for i in range (m):
    for n in range (n_H):
        vert_start = s * n
        vert_end = vert_start + f
        for k in range (n_W):
            horiz_start = s * k
            horiz_end = horiz_start + f
            for j in range(n_C):
                a_slice_prev = A_prev[i]
                if (mode == 'max'):
                    A[i, n, k, j] =np.max(a_slice_prev[vert_start:vert_end,horiz_start:horiz_end,j])
                else:
                    A[i, n, k, j] =  np.mean(a_slice_prev[vert_start:vert_end,horiz_start:horiz_end,j])
                

cache = (A_prev, hparameters)
assert(A.shape == (m, n_H, n_W, n_C))
print("A.shape = " + str(A.shape))


return A
```

Then If I called this function but expecting two variables as return (surprisingly works) but change the output size

```
 np.random.seed(1)
   A_prev = np.random.randn(2, 5, 5, 3)
   hparameters = {"stride" : 1, "f": 3}

   A,cache = pool_forward(A_prev, hparameters)
   print("A.shape = " + str(A.shape))
```

the results of print A before return and after return are different.

```
A.shape = (2, 3, 3, 3)
A.shape = (3, 3, 3)
```

but if we call the function for one veriable as consistant with return this will work fine, this is a strange behavior, I want to ask if any one haas an idea why this happans in python 3

Comment: Please include enough code for someone to re-create what you are describing.

Comment: If you `return A`, but then assign that returned value to `A, cache`, exactly what do you expect to happen? Did you mean to return a separate new value for `cache` as well? (Hint: where the code says `A_prev = np.random.randn(2, 5, 5, 3)`, try using **any value other than** `2` for the first dimension. Notice how this causes an exception instead? Does this give you some insight into how the returned value is being used in the assignment?)

Comment: Thanks Karl, I tried this: import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)
A_prev = np.random.randn(2, 5, 5, 3)
print(np.shape(A_prev))
A, cache = A_prev
print(np.shape(A))
print(np.shape(cache))            , if I edit the first dimension to 3 as you sugessted it raise an exception. but I'm asking why ? , I don't understand